# jquery select2 after ajax not working anymore

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, jquery-select2

I have a simple select2 control on my site placed in a div. When the site loads, everything works fine. However, if the html content of the div "simpleDiv", where the Select2 is placed, is loaded with Ajax, the Select2 is not showing the results anymore when triggered. 
That means, in this case the Select2 data is got from the Server, but never shown in the Select2.
And this all happens just when the "simpleDiv" html content is loaded with Ajax. Otherwise, everything works fine.

Can anyone help, please?

```
<div id='simpleDiv'>

<input type="hidden" id="MedikamentID" name="MedikamentID" class="fixed-width4" />

</div>

<script>
 $('#MedikamentID').select2({
                    placeholder: "[Medikament]",
                    allowClear: true,
                    minimumInputLength: 2,
                    ajax: {
                        url: "/Medikament/List",
                        dataType: 'json',
                        data: function (term, page) {

                            return {
                                query: term
                            };
                        },
                        results: function (data, page) {

                            return { results: data };
                        }
                    }
                });

</script>
```

Answer (score 6):

Whenever you change things using `.html()` or `.innerHTML`, essentially, the DOM gets reconstructed and all the javascript events and properties attached to them is lost. But the fix is simple. Just call Select 2 again after you finished inserting the new HTML. So something like:

```
$.ajax("example.php").done(function(data){
   $("#simpleDiv").html(data)
   $("#MedikamentID").select2(...) //rebuild select2
})
```

I attached a jsfiddle to illustrate this:
http://jsfiddle.net/HT3rP/1/

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This is actually what I'm doing. The Select2 gets registered again after the AJAX call. It even retrieves data from the Server. But the data is not showing in the select2.

Comment: I can't check what you have but can you see if this works? http://jsfiddle.net/HT3rP/1/ I added some fake ajax thing. The results are nonsense but it should test out ajax. For me this still works.

Comment: Hi, I could solve the Problem. It was obviously a conflict with some other javasciprt code in the application. As soon as I removed the JavaScript code, the select2 worked again.

Thank you.

Answer (score -2):

If I got your question correct, you may be having a similar problem related to [this stackoverflow problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13746894/newly-appended-objects-dont-respond-to-jquery-events-from-page-load)

You could try something like this

```
$(document).on("ready", "#MedikamentID", function () {
    $(this).select2({
       // options go here
    });
});
```

Comment: Since the element is added after the page load, waiting for the page load won't suffice.

Comment: Thank u for your answer. But this is actually not the Problem as the control gets registred. Only after AJAX it is completely broken.